# How to loop the variables in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, variables, loops, each

Say `position` starts at `0`, `c.width` equals `700`. After I click on `#button` twice, the animation should stop working. But it didnt. I guess it's because the values of my variables remain the same after every click on `#button`.

How do I loop the variables so they update the value every time I click on `#button`? (The value of `position` should change every time I click on `#button`, but I don't know how...)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var c=$('#content');
        var position=c.position();
        var w=c.width();
        var status=w - position.left;
        if(status>500){
            c.stop().animate({left:position.left - 100},300)};
            var position=c.position();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: That 2nd `var position=c.position();` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your math, `status` will not only always be greater than 500, but it will increase as well.

```
Click -> 500
Click -> 700
Click -> 900
Click -> 1100
```

You can change your math like so:

```
if (status < 900) {
    c.stop().animate({
        left: position.left - 100
    }, 300)
};
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qbLd2/